# Is there a quick way to compare 3 ternary numbers according to a simple rule set?

Tags: java, math

Given 3 ternary (base 3) numbers of equal length (they can be padded on the left with zeros), is there a quick and simple way to compare each place value (or column) such that each column is composed of 3 different numbers or 3 of the same number.

For example:

```
Good pairs:     || Bad pairs:
________________||________________ 
101 | 000 | 012 || 111 | 012 | 002 
212 | 111 | 112 || 122 | 120 | 022
020 | 222 | 212 || 120 | 202 | 102
```

#### What I have tried so far

My best solution currently is to add up the 3 numbers, but add them like decimal numbers instead of (so the first good pair would become 333 instead of 1110). Then I check each individual number and check if it is divisible by 3.

At first I was checking if the entire number was divisible by 3, but that fails on a lot of numbers.

```
00
10
11
--
21 % 3 == 0
```

As you can see just dividing by 3 isn't a good enough check since you can tell with a quick glance that the columns actually fail the rules I've set.
Here's the method I wrote that checks it the correct way I explained:

```
//The 3 numbers are originally decimal numbers
private static boolean ternary(int a, int b, int c)
{
    //Convert each number to a ternary number, add them and assign the result to a string
    //This is the best base conversion code I was able to find using native java
    String ternary = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(a, 3))
                + Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(b, 3)) 
                + Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(c, 3)));

    //For each digit in the number, check if it is divisible by 3. If not, return false
    for (int i = 0; i < ternary.length(); i++)
        if (Integer.parseInt(ternary.charAt(i) + "") % 3 != 0)
            return false;
    //If all the numbers passed the test, return true
    return true;
}
```

I have also messed around with adding the numbers as decimal and converting the result to a ternary number and trying to check the properties to no avail.
I have a second method that acts like the above but without using Strings. Instead it divides the number by 10000, 1000, etc. since you cannot do .charAt() on a number.

## The real Q

My intuition tells me there needs to be a much simpler way to do this, but I have yet to discover it. I have spent way too much trying to come up with an elegant solution, but I'm quite stuck. This may be more of a math question than a programming one, but I think someone here might be able to point me in the right direction.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially have a 3x3 matrix where each column must sum to either `0` (all elements in the column are `0`), `3` (all elements in the column are `1` **or** the elements in the column are a permutation of `0`, `1`, and `2`), or `6` (all elements in the column are `2`).

Because the columns must sum to either `0`, `3`, or `6`, we can simply check that the sum is divisible by `3`.

The code to check this would be as follows:

```
private static boolean ternary(int a, int b, int c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if ((a % 3 + b % 3 + c % 3) % 3 != 0) {
            return false;
        }

        a /= 3;
        b /= 3;
        c /= 3;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Because `a`, `b`, and `c` are input as decimal (base-10), we can use `n % 3` (on each value) to get the least significant ternary digits, and return `false` if their sum is not divisible by `3`.

However, we then need to divide each value by `3` to effectively *drop* the least significant ternary digit.

---

This is also personal preference, but the calls to `a /= 3`, `b /= 3`, and `c /= 3` can be moved into the *increment* portion of the for-loop:

```
private static boolean ternary(int a, int b, int c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++, a /= 3, b /= 3, c /= 3) {
        if ((a % 3 + b % 3 + c % 3) % 3 != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Solid answer, but it is constrained to ternaries of length three. Suggest changing for loop to while loop
`while (a != 0 || b != 0 || c != 0) { //modulo goodness here}`

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. Much simpler than what I was doing